# WCF Custom Operation Behaviour Implementation Order

Tags: wcf

I have two custom operation behaviours which validates and input and token separately, they work fine, however I want them to be implemented in a particular order.

I'd like `RequiredRequestValidate` gets called before `RequiredToken` which is not the case atm.

What I have is:

```
[RequiredRequestValidate]
[RequiredToken]
public UsersResponse GetUsers(UserAuthorizationRequest request)
{
     // Whatever here ...
}
```